# Datetime syntax seems valid, but causes a syntax error

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to query my customlogs table (Eg: CustomData_CL) by giving the time range. The result of this query will be the filtered time ranged data. I want to find out the data size of the resulted output.

Query which I have used to fetch the time ranged output:

```
CustomData_CL
| where TimeGenerated  between (datetime(2022–09–14 04:00:00) .. datetime(2020–09–14 05:00:00))
```

But it is giving the following error:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the characters with code point 8211.
These are not standard hyphens (`-`) .

```
let p_str = "(datetime(2022–09–14 04:00:00) .. datetime(2020–09–14 05:00:00))";
print str = p_str
| mv-expand str = extract_all("(.)", str) to typeof(string)
| extend dec = to_utf8(str)[0]
```

| str | dec |
| --- | --- |
| ( | 40 |
| d | 100 |
| a | 97 |
| t | 116 |
| e | 101 |
| t | 116 |
| i | 105 |
| m | 109 |
| e | 101 |
| ( | 40 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 0 | 48 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 50 |
| – | **8211** |
| 0 | 48 |
| 9 | 57 |
| – | **8211** |
| 1 | 49 |
| 4 | 52 |
| 32 |  |
| 0 | 48 |
| 4 | 52 |
| : | 58 |
| 0 | 48 |
| 0 | 48 |
| : | 58 |
| 0 | 48 |
| 0 | 48 |
| ) | 41 |
| 32 |  |
| . | 46 |
| . | 46 |
| 32 |  |
| d | 100 |
| a | 97 |
| t | 116 |
| e | 101 |
| t | 116 |
| i | 105 |
| m | 109 |
| e | 101 |
| ( | 40 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 0 | 48 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 0 | 48 |
| – | **8211** |
| 0 | 48 |
| 9 | 57 |
| – | **8211** |
| 1 | 49 |
| 4 | 52 |
| 32 |  |
| 0 | 48 |
| 5 | 53 |
| : | 58 |
| 0 | 48 |
| 0 | 48 |
| : | 58 |
| 0 | 48 |
| 0 | 48 |
| ) | 41 |
| ) | 41 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02NQQrCMBBF94XeYcgqAS1jqWAVTyJSQjOVQJuEOkoFF97BG3oSE%202iMAwM7/35PTGE5sojHEFIo5nYDiRLLMvP6411XJsKsNojxlFQFLCUcCltZ0mJQ56F0TqG/%20NfQZ49YbivaQramRnQxKNuudF9L4UslFgloIA98COQ72Q8rbuoFI4yxaShNibZNzfudomrE56/gDOCUMcAAAA=)

**Update, per OP request:**

Please note that in addition to the use of a wrong character that caused the syntax error, your 2nd datetime year was wrong.

```
// Generation of mock table. Not part of the solution
let CustomData_CL = datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime)[datetime(2022-09-14 04:30:00)];
// Solution starts here
CustomData_CL
| where TimeGenerated  between (datetime(2022-09-14 04:00:00) .. datetime(2022-09-14 05:00:00))
```

| TimeGenerated |
| --- |
| 2022-09-14T04:30:00Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WNMQuCUBRGd+H9h2/UQd/LbMhoMmiJltoi4pk3lNQXesWlH99TbBBq+zice4+U2FNNjebC1DAPVOb+BOu0pABHw3jphgfOOaE1ZTd4wimJkXQtm2qnWd+SA7bI7BoP3XNR0fSVsthyYku8y3e5oQpDX639RQQVxUsVK+VdN8KREqepgZZtuUVODQln1hLOG/3AMQsBKXFPVMP9E1JjCEGAn8JqErwPiSSIkxUBAAA=)

Comment: Can you please post the KQL query to fetch the data for the given time range ?

Comment: See updated answer. It is exactly your code but with the right hyphen (`-`) character. You probably copied your code from Outlook or something

Comment: See updated answer (again)

Comment: Have rectified the hyphen in my query. Right now able to fetch data within timeframe. How can we fetch the datasize of this query?

Comment: Per SO guidelines, a post should address a single issue. Please accept the answer and post another question for that.

Comment: Posted another question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73715415/how-can-we-fetch-the-datasize-of-a-kusto-query-in-log-analytics-workspace

Answer (score 0):

I'm preparing the material for a KQL course, and I thought about creating a challenge, based on your question.

Check out what happened when I posted your code into [Kusto Web Explorer](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/)...

How cool is that?!

[image: KWE]