# How can we fetch the datasize of a kusto query in Log Analytics Workspace?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I want to fetch the data size of a specific kusto query.

**Query:**

```
CustomData_CL
| where TimeGenerated  between (datetime(2022-09-14 04:00:00) .. datetime(2022-09-14 05:00:00))
```

Can anyone please suggest on the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[estimate_data_size()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/estimate-data-sizefunction)

```
CustomData_CL
| where TimeGenerated  between (datetime(2022-09-14 04:00:00) .. datetime(2022-09-14 05:00:00))
| summarize sum(estimate_data_size(*))
```